# Key Error When Creating Training Data in TensorFlow Object Detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection

I keep on getting this error with my new training data. I have tried the example data and that works but when I use my own, it gives a "Key Error". The only thing different to my data and the training data is that mine has more classes.
Full Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "object_detection/create_tf_record.py", line 185, in <module>
   tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\edupt\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "object_detection/create_tf_record.py", line 180, in main
image_dir, train_examples)
  File "object_detection/create_tf_record.py", line 152, in create_tf_record
tf_example = dict_to_tf_example(data, label_map_dict, image_dir)
  File "object_detection/create_tf_record.py", line 97, in dict_to_tf_example
classes.append(label_map_dict[class_name])
KeyError: '300424'  <---------- THAT IS THE NAME OF ONE OF THE CLASSES
```

Comment: please share your code

Comment: Lol I have just found the issue, for some reason one of the xmls had a combine class id of two different classes in the same boundingbox

Comment: @engiego Hell dear.I have same problem on the pet dataset. : KeyError: 'leonberger'
how did you solve the problem ?